# mt symlink creation while manually installing Boost on Linux / Ubuntu

Tags: linux, boost, ubuntu, installation, symlink

When I am manually building and installing Boost 1.48 in Ubuntu 10.04 it do not create symlink (symbolic link) with -mt suffix even though I compiled with multi threading option but I must need that. What is the best way to solve this problem? and How?

Comment: Is it specified somewhere that it should be creating these symlinks?

Comment: The reason is one external library looks library with -mt extension's so ... anyway I solved the problem by compiling the library myself :)